# Probability of guessing lottery combination

Tags: probability

Lets say we have a lottery draw every day (the winning combination is reset every day). There is a finite number of combinations (14 million).

Do I have a higher chance of guessing the combination if I play once every day (for all 365 days in a year), than just playing once (1 day only)?

I'm asking this question because it seems to me if you draw the numbers every day, then the chances of guessing the winning combination are always the same, hence it should be equally possible to win by playing only once or for a full year.

Comment: no, the events are independent.

Comment: On a day-to-day basis, no. But if you play the game 100 times, it's more likely that you'll win at least once, compared to playing only once.

Answer (score 1):

Day or year, chances are so near 0, I hope you're doing it for the fun of it.

Of course, chances are better if you buy a ticket every day for a year. Or better yet for 14 million days (almost 40,000 years). Then your expected number of wins would be about 1.

Charlie Brown to Lucy upon her purchase of a lottery ticket, as he declined: "We both have about the same chance of winning and I still have my dollar."